# Stop a TCP stream when listening to all ports

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, stream

I'm programming an application that listens to ports for specific packets using REGEX. I can see the original TCP Stream, but I'm wondering if this is possible to intercept and stop this stream without any packet forging library.

Example:
A user navigates on a page where there is the word P*RN or "J*st** Bi*ber", and automatically, he loses this specific connection.

If I cannot do it, maybe I'll replace some HTMLElements on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a proxy server, so that all traffic from your users to the internet (and back) will go through your proxy. You can implement the proxy using the .NET networking API (no packet forging). When you want to drop the connection, you can either close the TCP stream, or send back an error response.

This solution has some problems too:

- you have to implement specific proxy for each protocol you want to filter (SMTP, IMAP, POP3)
- you need to force your users to use your proxy server when connecting to internet (this could be configured at network level)
- it will not work with SSL (HTTPS), since the traffic is encrypted

**Edit**
I don't think there is a way how to intercept TCP streams using .NET API. However you can *forward* TCP streams (accepting client connection and then forwarding all communication between the client and the server). Since you accepted the client TCP connection, you can also terminate it.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, it's maybe too drastic to close a connection and act like a firewall. I guess it's more clean, cool and '2012' to censor by playing with the HTMLElements. I.e.: replacing HTML images with a stop sign.